# Angular2 RC1 Pipes Always Passing Undefined

Tags: angular, angular2-pipe

After upgrading to RC1 from Beta, pipes don't seem to be correctly passing data.  I am receiving the following:

```
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined
```

This is an old plunker, but it shows the way I am using pipes within my application.  https://plnkr.co/edit/DHLVc0?p=preview

Sometimes I get no errors at all and it treats the page as if there were no pipes whatsoever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On version **2.0.0-beta.16**, pipes had breaking changes. From [angular2 changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

> pipes now take a variable number of arguments, and not an array that contains all arguments.

So, instead of `transform(value, args){}`  it's now `transform(value,args...){}`

**before**

```
transform(value, [arg1,arg2,arg3])
```

**Now**

```
transform(value, arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

If you don't want to make any changes to your pipes, you could still use them but you need to change the way you add arguments

Before:

```
{{someValue|somePipe:arg1:arg2}}
```

change it to:

```
{{someValue|somePipe:[arg1,arg2]}} // this will work with the new syntax without changing anything in the pipe itself
```

Or, the better way, is to change your pipes and make the transform method accepts multiple arguments instead of one array.

Now, going to the plunk on your question:

All you need to make it work with the new versions is to change:

```
transform(input:any, [config = '+']): any{
```

To

```
transform(input:any, config = '+'): any{
```

And that's it. Because in your code, you never call the pipe with more than one argument. It's always an array of arguments, that fits perfectly with the new syntax.

[Here is your plunk fixed](http://plnkr.co/edit/7llMKCZg5Sj5BdCIgK8i?p=preview)

Comment: Perfect, thanks!~ I only looked at the RC0 and RC1 changelogs do'oh