# angular 2 Pipe stopped working in 2.0.0-beta.17

Tags: angular, pipe

Recently, I updated code for ngFor from "#" to "let" and the pipe on one of the existing loop stopped working.

Html looks like this:

```
<a class="product" *ngFor="let repeatProduct of (_products | CategoryMatchPipe: selectedProductCategory)" (click)="setPreviewProduct(repeatProduct)">
    <div class="img" [ngStyle]="backgroundImageStyle(repeatProduct.mainImageSource)"></div>
    <h4>{{repeatProduct.name}}</h4>
  </a>
```

There is a pipe, CategoryMatchPipe, used in the ngFor loop on products.

The categoryMatchPipe looks like this:

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from "angular2/core";

@Pipe(
{
    name: "CategoryMatchPipe"
    ,pure: false                                         
}
)
export class CategoryMatchPipe implements PipeTransform{

    transform(value: any, args? : any){
        if(value){
            let category = args[0];
            return value.filter( product => product.category === category);
        }
    }
}
```

When I debug the pipe, it seems to be filtering the array fine but I don't see any products.
Any idea what is the problem?

Comment: related question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37197293/angular2-rc1-pipes-always-passing-undefined/37198683#37198683

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you.